# Data Matrix 2d barcode and fusion pro

Tags: printing, barcode, datamatrix

I'm in a bit of a stump. Not sure how many people here are familiar with the plug-in "Fusion Pro" for Acrobat but maybe it doesn't matter.

I need to create a 2d Barcode and have it read data for 3 or more columns in excel i.e.: A, B, C, D

As said earlier, I've been creating these barcodes through fusion pro and it's called a "DataMatrix" does DataMatrix imply that the barcode is 2D or are the other different names that 2D barcodes can have?

Thank you!

ALSO: If you have a solution for this through another software please don't hesitate to mention that. I'm not bounded to just use FusionPro.

Answer (score 1):

DataMatrix does imply 2D barcodes. There are several encoding strategies for DataMatrix and other 2D barcodes (QR Code and PDF417 are two highly popular ones). What you want to do is "Tab-delimit" your data, so Excel puts the fields in different columns. That means embedding the ASCII control character HT (for horizontal tab) in between your fields.

Each of the symbologies has a method for embedding control and escape characters in the data portion of the barcode and I would like to think that the barcode generator - Fusion Pro, in this case, would have some mechanism as well.

You may need to embed a CR (carriage return) or LF (line feed) or both at the very end of the data to get Excel to accept the input and automatically move between lines, or you may have to scan into notepad, then import to Excel.

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix for details on data encoding.